# Is curl's --upload-file a post request?

Tags: curl, post

I'm a little bit confused about curl's "--upload-file" argument. The man-page just states that it "transfers the specified local file to the remote URL.".

Is this a post request? If no, what is it then and how would this look like in an actual HTML5 client app?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is a PUT request.

From the [manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html#uploading) (`-T` is single-dashed for `--upload-file`):

> Upload all data on stdin to a specified HTTP site:
>
> ```
> curl -T - http://www.upload.com/myfile
> ```
>
> Note that the HTTP server must have been configured to accept PUT before this can be done successfully.
>
> For other ways to do HTTP data upload, see the POST section below.