# post request with Python requests lib returning status 405

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I am uploading a file to server using requests lib in Python. I read its documentation and some stackoverflow questions and implemented following code:

```
url = "http://example.com/file.csv"
id = "user-id"
password = "password"
headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    response = requests.post(url=url, files={'file':f}, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username=id, password=password),headers=headers)
```

But this code is not working, response.status_code returning 405 and response.reason returning `Method Not Allowed`.  When i upload file using curl command on terminal it works fine and file gets uploaded:

```
curl -u user-id:password -T file/path/on/local/machine/file.csv "http://example.com/file.csv"
```

Can someone please help here.

Comment: Why are you setting the content type? That's the wrong content type for a file upload. `files` takes care of the content type for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for quick response. Trein solution worked. I am new to these server stuffs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40691850/is-curls-upload-file-a-post-request). In reality, `curl --upload-file` performs a `PUT` not a `POST`. If you want to mimic what curl does, you might want to try:

```
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    response = requests.put(url=url, files={'file':f}, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username=id, password=password), headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks @Trein it works. I am new to these server stuffs.